# Is it possible that an electric field exists like $E=kx$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

Is it possible for an electric field $\vec{E}$ to exist such that its electric field intensity increases continuously, something like $E=kx$, while all the $\vec{E}$ pointing in the same direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, but only in a space filled with charge (of such
a concentration as to  produce the effect).   Such a field has divergence
(which means it cannot happen in empty space) but no curl (which would
necessitate currents as well as charges).

Comment: Interestingly the divergence of this field is $k$ which is the same as the divergence of a field $E = ky$. Meaning that they both give the same charge distributions. Presumably it is boundary conditions that establishes the difference in the two case, but just now I'm having trouble visualizing it.